# How to switch between PHP versions on Ubuntu Nginx

Tags: php-7, nginx, ubuntu

I have PHP 7.0 and 7.2 installed.

For now, I use PHP 7.0.

How can I switch to PHP 7.2?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Please use to below command

```
sudo update-alternatives --config php
```

After run above command select the PHP version that you need to use.

> Press  to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: For example 2

After switching below command used to restart the PHP and Nginx server.

```
sudo service nginx restart
sudo service php7.1-fpm or php7.2-fpm  restart
```

Please try above code. If you have any help let me know.

Comment: If it is helpful then accept answer.

Answer (score 8):

For Nginx, we simply need to update the PHP-FPM socket in its configuration file. But before that make sure that the PHP-FPM is installed for your version and is running as a service.

Take a backup of the default configuration file and then open it up in your favourite text editor.

```
$ cp /etc/nginx/sites-available/default /etc/nginx/sites-available/default.bak
$ sudo vim /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
```

Change the FastCGI backend to use the new PHP-FPM socket, save and exit the file

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
}
```

Run the configuration test

```
$ nginx -t
```

Restart the web server

```
$ sudo service nginx restart
```

For more information [visit here](https://opensenselabs.com/blog/tech/change-php-version-drupal-website-apache-nginx)

Comment: This is a critical step for nginx users. I was facing difficulty after switching version of PHP, restarting the php driver and nginx server, but the site would still not load. It wasn't until I saw this answer that I remembered I have the php version specified in the configuration file. Thanks!

Comment: What if I have fastcgi_pass set to `127.0.0.1:9250`? Changing it to a unix socket breaks my server and using `update-alternatives` only changes the CLI PHP version. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

**For Apache:**

```
sudo a2dismod php7.0
sudo a2enmod php7.2
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Reference: [Link](https://www.tecmint.com/install-different-php-versions-in-ubuntu/)

Comment: Didn't OP ask about Nginx, not Apache?

Comment: `a2` stands for Apache 2, so this won't work for Nginx.